# Как поменять значение переменной используя функцию? Python

Tags: python

возникла необходимость поменять значение переменной используя функцию.
Выглядеть это должно примерно так:

```
a = 0
change(a) или change('a')
print(a) # 1
```

Возможно это как-либо сделать или единственное решение это:

```
a = change(a)
```

Comment: Может, вам нужен словарь dct = {'a' : 0}?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Python можно перезаписывать глобальные переменные таким образом

```
a = 1

def change():
    global a
    a = 2

change()
print(a)
```

Если вы хотите перезаписать переменную по ее имени, как указано в вопросе то можно так

```
a = 1

def change(t):
    globals().update({t: 2})

change('a')
print(a)
```

Но не понятно зачем так делать